# Using quadratic equations to solve ratio questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There are two parts to the question but I have answered the first part.

The exchange rate in 1964 was $x$ dollars to £1. An American tourist remembered that in 1952 he needed $1.5$ dollars more for each £1 he received in exchange. Using these facts only, write down expressions for the number of pounds he received for \$100 in 1964 and in 1952.

In 1952 he received £12 less for his \$100 than in 1964. Form an equation in $x$ and show that this can be reduced to $2x^2+3x-25=0$. Solve this equation for $x$.

For part one, the answers were $100/x$ for 1964 and $100/(x+1.5)$ for 1952 - I found that quite straightforward.  I cannot work out the second part though.  I assumed that the equation would be $\frac{100}{x+1.5} - 12$ but I cannot see how to form a quadratic equation from this.

I have a supplementary question.  Where can I find more material like this - solving ratio questions using quadratic equations?  I have never come across it before, and find it very interesting.

Comment: This tagging system is hopeless.  Also, the formatting is wrong,  The original question read:

Comment: I have no idea what this comment means. It ends "original question read:" and then stops!

Comment: Please check that you have used parentheses properly.  Note that you can type $\frac{100}{x + 1.5}$ by typing `$\frac{100}{x + 1.5}$`.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing expressions with equations.  Also, you subtracted when you should have added.  The tourist would have needed $12$ additional 1952 pounds to get the same number of pounds he received in 1964.

The amount the American tourist would receive in pounds for $\$100$ at $x$ dollars per pound in $1964$ is $100/x$.  The amount the same tourist would have received in 1952 in pounds for $\$100$ at $(x + 1.5)$ dollars per pound is $\frac{100}{x + 1.5}$.  Given that the amount the tourist received in exchange for $\$100$ in 1952 was $12$ pounds less than he received in $1964$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{100}{x} & = \frac{100}{x + 1.5} + 12\\
\frac{100}{x} & = \frac{100}{x + 1.5} + \frac{12x + 18}{x + 1.5}\\
\frac{100}{x} & = \frac{118 + 12x}{x + 1.5}\\
100x + 150 & = 82x + 12x^2\\
0 & = 12x^2 + 18x - 150\\
0 & = 2x^2 + 3x - 25
\end{align*}
I will leave the remaining steps to you.

Comment: I would like to thank all of the people who sent solutions to this question and so promptly.  Thank you all very much.  Is it possible to send responses to individuals who have answered the question or can I only send a general comment like this one?

Comment: When you leave a comment below an answer, only the person who posted that answer is notified.  To thank Doug M, you will have to leave a message beneath his answer.  I am glad that you found our answers helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The USD / GBP exchange rate was pegged 2.80 by the Bretton-Woods system for the entire period between 1952 and 1964.

But you are not here for economic history...

The change in the value of 100 dollars is 12 pounds.

$\frac{100}{x} - \frac {100}{x+1.5} = 12$

multiply both sides by $(x)(x+1.5)$ to clear the fractions.

$100(x+1.5) - 100x = 12(x)(x+1.5)$

Multiply out and simplify

$150 = 12x^2 + 18x\\
12x^2 + 18x - 150 = 0\\
2x^2 + 3x - 25 = 0$

As required

Factor the polynomial or apply the quadratic formula (likely necessary).  One factor will give a negative value for $x$ and can be rejected.